# How to require cookbook libraries in kitchen serverspec tests

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen, serverspec

On a cookbook I defined a class Rds::Checks that shares methods for building unix commands for bash/execute resources and Guards. A sample of the file libraries/checks.rb is:

```
module Rds
 class Checks
   class << self

     def ssh_config_entry_present host, config_file, key_name
       "cat #{config_file} | grep #{key_name}"   
     end

     def redmine_migrated user, pass, name
       "if [ `mysql -u#{user} -p#{pass} -e 'select count(id) FROM #{name}.users;' | sed -n '2 p'` -gt 0 ]; then echo '0'; else echo '1'; fi"
     end

   end
 end
end
```

On LWPR providers, recipes and chefspec tests the file is loaded without problems, but when I use it inside serverspec through `kitchen verify` it raise an error.

```
paolo@tower:~/cookbooks/rds$ cat test/integration/install/serverspec/localhost/install_spec.rb
...
    it 'do migrations' do
      cmd = Rds::Checks.redmine_migrated 
      expect(command(cmd).stdout).to eq 0
    end
...


paolo@tower:~/cookbooks/rds$ kitchen verify

...

    NameError:
      uninitialized constant Rds
```

I would really like keep methods that builds bash/sh commands on a common layer so that I can test it separately and don't bother about them on unit and integration tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to load it very manually, probably add the temp folder holding the cookbook data to the load path, I think it is under `/tmp/kitchen/cookbooks`. Add the correct `libraries/` folder and then require as per normal. Overall the converge and verify phases have nothing to do with each other, since test-kitchen can be used with things other than Chef.

You might want to look at something like [minitest handler](https://github.com/btm/minitest-handler-cookbook) which runs tests in the Chef converge context, or the [audit mode proposal](https://github.com/opscode/chef-rfc/pull/69) which does similar things.

Using something like one of those, you would write your tests in the cookbook itself, so converge would actually be both converging the node and then running the tests, and verify would either be a no-op or would run additional, external tests.

Comment: could be maybe a solution to share this library as gem and add them to the Gemfile?

Comment: Sure, that's a lot more work though. You can force busser-serverspec to install custom gems like that, but it isn't super easy.

Comment: busser-rspec and busser-serverspec accept a Gemfile, so it wouldn't be too bad to force them to install a custom gem.